# Can I change my working holiday to a visitor while the working holiday is still active?

Tags: united-kingdom, canadian-citizens, overstay, working-holiday-visas, uk-visitor-visa

My Visa for UK expires on the 25th of April. I'm from Canada. If I go to South Ireland at some point before my Tier 5 expiry, can I switch my current working holiday to a Visitor visa? If so, would I need a specific visa to enter Ireland?

If I cannot switch while my current visa is active, I would assume I have to wait for it to expire. I know there is a 14 day grace period before I have to leave the country. I'm trying to find some way to stay an extra few months after my working holiday expires.. is there any possible way to go about getting a visitor visa?

Comment: Under which Immigration Rule is there a 14 day grace period? 6A (245ZL) states the validity of the visa is 2 years, no extensions allowed.Also see https://www.gov.uk/tier-5-youth-mobility ‘How long you can stay’. Ireland is part of the Common Travel Area https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/138745/what-do-non-eu-schengen-citizens-need-to-do-when-travelling-within-the-common-tr (see under ‘Travel Ireland to UK’)

Comment: @Traveller https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/immigration/stay-in-uk/overstayed-visa/&ved=2ahUKEwi0w4KFtaDoAhXhQEEAHdlRCdwQFjACegQICRAH&usg=AOvVaw276gjZW_RD3hqA7Stgp87_&cshid=1584410768108

Comment: *30 days, not 14. I read somewhere else they changed the grace period to 14 though, in 2017

Comment: @Traveller a grace period is not an extension, you seem to be misunderstanding. I'm also looking for a way to stay in the UK by means of visitor status or application, even if temporarily. Not necessarily an extension of anything. Looking for some way to change my Tier 5 to a visitor or leave to another country that will allow me to try and get one on arrival back. Until I know there is no other way at all, I won't consider Canada an option. If that's my only option fine, but best option, no.

Comment: I realise a grace period is not an extension. What I meant is you have to leave by the visa expiry date. You should also consider that, having spent time in the UK with a YMV, you will be seen as having ‘built up a life’ in the UK. If you try to return as a visitor you risk being denied entry under V4.2 as not being a genuine visitor. And remember that if you overstay, you will have to declare that in any future visa applications that ask the question.

Comment: Grace periods only apply when the type of visa held is eligible for extension https://www.davidsonmorris.com/overstay-in-uk/

Comment: @Traveller in that same link you just sent saying  the grace period is only for when the visa is held for extension, it does not say that. It says "Leaving the UK
Paragraphs A320 and 320(7B) of the Immigration Rules state that you have to leave the UK voluntarily within 30 days of your visa expiring in the UK." And multiple other places it says if I stay after the 30 days I'll be considered an overstayer..

Comment: That’s not a 30 day grace period. It means that after 30 days UK Immigration might come looking for you, and you’ll be entering the realms of possible enforcement action. Leaving the UK voluntarily after an overstay can be a means to avoid an automatic ban for breach of Immigration laws. https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/606970/GI-Re-entry-bans-v7.pdf I understand why, but you’re looking for possibilities to stay in the U.K. that don’t exist. If you stay after your visa expires, even 1 day, you are officially overstaying.

Comment: I'm trying to remember which (all?) of the border force--UK, AU, NZ--had at least one episode on someone wanting a visitor visa shortly after a working holiday visa. They were very sceptical and I think denied entry. If you say you want to travel as a tourist, they'll say you should have done that already.

Comment: It's not so much that I want to say but more over that I'm trying to find out if the government will be implementing any extensions or anything because of the current virus situation. My flights back to Canada have been suspended by the airline because of the virus. My apartment I was supposed to move into is not allowing me to anymore because I'm supposed to self quarantine and they don't want to risk getting the other housemates sick. I just have no where to go and I have no idea what to do or how to even get back if I legally can't stay here until it's over.

Comment: @Jake Flights to Canada are still available https://www.google.com/flights?hl=en-gb Contact your airline to re-book or get another flight NOW and claim a refund on your cancelled booking when you get back. Make an effort. Air Canada cancelled my friend’s return flight from Cuba on Sunday;by Monday she’d booked a 15 hour bus journey to leave from Havana, she’s now home after travelling 48 hours via Madrid>London with a different airline. Stop hoping to be able to stay legally. The UK government has better things to do than help visitors who have options to leave before it’s too late. Go home.

Comment: @Jake Which is it? You previously wanted to stay to be with your girlfriend, and now you’re saying you have to self-quarantine? Sorry, but I’m losing patience.

Answer (score 0):

- Q1  Do I need a specific visa to enter Ireland?

The Common Travel Area (CTA) consists of the UK, Guernsey, Jersey, the Isle of Man and Ireland. Non-EU/Schengen citizens receive an Irish entry stamp, even if arriving from the UK. For visa-free nationals, this lets them stay in Ireland for max 3 months. The time those without a UK visa are allowed in Ireland also includes the rest of the CTA. For travellers visa-exempt for both the UK and Ireland, the visa exemption is 6 months in the UK but only 3 months in Ireland, meaning if a Canadian citizen visitor enters the CTA through Ireland, they'll only be allowed 3 months in the whole CTA. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/138745/what-do-non-eu-schengen-citizens-need-to-do-when-travelling-within-the-common-tr

- Q2 Is there a way to extend my working holiday?

There is no 14 day grace period because grace periods only apply to categories of visa eligible for extension. A Tier 5 Youth Mobility Visa is valid for two years, no extensions are allowed and you must leave the UK before your visa expires.  https://www.gov.uk/tier-5-youth-mobility If you don’t leave by the expiry date, you will be out of status and considered to be overstaying https://www.davidsonmorris.com/overstay-in-uk/

Prior to the COVID-19 crisis, you could have exited the UK to a nearby Schengen country and re-entered as a visa-free national for up to 6 months, provided you could satisfy UK Immigration, if asked,  about your purpose in returning and your intention to leave (see V4.2 https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules). Given the impending EU travel ban https://www.businessinsider.com/coronavirus-eu-to-ban-non-essential-travel-for-thirty-days-2020-3 since you are not an EU citizen, and will not be a long-term resident after your visa expires, a visa run to Schengen is no longer possible.

Your best option is to return to Canada.

Comment: Wouldn't a Schengen visa run still be possible since the UK is exempt from that travel ban?  From the article you just linked - "Members of the Schengen travel area — including the non-EU members Iceland, Liechtenstein, Norway, and Switzerland — will not be affected by the rules. The United Kingdom, which left the EU in January but remains in a transition period with the bloc, will also be exempt."

Comment: @Jake But you are not an EU citizen, or a long-term resident after your visa expires. Why are you so desperate to stay given the COVID-19 outbreak is worse in the U.K. than your home country and predicted to get much worse very soon?

Comment: My girlfriend (UK) and I, (Canadian) have been planning a trip back to Canada for months.. Our flight is booked for April 6th and there's a chance Virgin Atlantic to France for the layover before Calgary, will be cancelled anyways. The airline may let us reschedule but the visa expiry is an issue so I have no idea what to to do. I don't really feel like leaving the love of my life on the other side of the planet during a global pandemic. That's why I don't feel like leaving when it's "predicted to get much worse".... Who knows how long we would be separated because of this stuff.

Comment: I'm not just wanting to stay here because I think it's fun during a pandemic in England... I'm pretty sure anyone would do the same and try to be with a loved one as long as they could during a global crisis...

Comment: @Jake I completely understand, my partner lives in Cuba and I’m in the U.K. I came back from my last visit in mid Feb, we had plans to go to Barbados on 18 April with my family, but now I’ve no idea when or if I’ll see him again.

Comment: I think the UK exemption is to people in the UK going to and from Europe, not necessarily a citizen.. I think I may be able to cross over for a visa run. I'll be contacting someone today about it and I'll post here the information I get.

Comment: @Jake Post it as an answer to your question rather than a comment, it will be more visible that way. Or better still, post it as a separate question entirely. Although the ban applies to ‘visitors from non-EU states’. Make sure to confirm you’d be able to re-enter the U.K. as a visitor - you can’t do that until your visa has expired, unless you cancel it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105637/discussion-between-traveller-and-jake).

Comment: @Traveller "Make sure to confirm you’d be able to re-enter the U.K. as a visitor - you can’t do that until your visa has expired, unless you cancel it." I remember people saying here when they moved out of the UK (having Indefinite Leave to Remain), then came back within 2 years as a visitor, the immigration officer cancelled their ILR and stamped them through as visitors, because of that I also heard an advice of not travelling to the UK with ILR unless you're intending to move back and continue to live in the country rather than visit. I assume the same might apply to visas?